# Cannot RDP to Azure VM

Tags: azure

I am having trouble Connecting to my VM's on Azure.  Yesterday I was not able to connect to any of them and today I can log into only one.

Upon clicking the Connect button on the Portal and downloading the RDP it just hangs on the "Remote Desktop Connetion" dialog where is says "Configuring Remote Session".

A work colleqgue of mine also has the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's an issue with the portal. Could you try connecting to the VM with Visual Studio (explained [here](http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/manage-your-subscriptions-with-the-windows-azure-tools-for-visual-studio/) in detail)?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that port 3389 is opened. For more details you can see http://nabaruns.blogspot.in/2012/11/common-port-related-troubleshoot-in.html

Answer (score 1):

In addition to making sure port 3389 is open on the VM's Network Security Group make sure that your VM has a public IP. You can check this by looking at the Overview of your VM's blade. If you do not see a public IP listed then you will need to assign one.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-public-ip-address